# Reactjs with Azure

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure

I have a problem, i have created webApp, using Nodejs 8.1, its operational. I uploaded my code using a zip file. I ran npm install and start (to test) in the kudu,cmd debug console, they both succeed. It's not a reactjs .Net application (not my choice ..). I still can't see my website, I have tested different web.config files,obviously not using then locally. Should I use a VM... I need ideas. I can go thru the directories if directoryBrowse enabled = True. So there is some kind of response ...

Comment: Trial and error. What if all you have is a plain `index.html` page? Does that work?

Comment: Well no error, but nothing displays.

Comment: Well a blank page wouldn't display anything. You just need to keep trying.

Comment: I could use .deployment files  (they generate web.config)  but I don't know where to put them .

Comment: No index.html, has code in it .....

Comment: I mean make one without anything in it. That way you can determine what the problem is

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted to do, but I read a book on react (yeah I have got thrown in there) and found the answer. I guess that's part of learning new librairy/technologie

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy I was sooo far off, I needed to build and upload the build.. I found the answer here. [Here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024412/deploying-react-project-on-azure?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)